# How to prevent Alignment to round the X & Y value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here's the code:

```
double x = -1.0;
double y = 1.0;

final radians = angle * e / 180.0;

y = tan(radians) * x;

return Alignment(x, y);
```

Then when I print out:

> flutter: radians: -0.09060951997193932 
>   flutter: y: 0.09085830765468121 
>   flutter: x: -1.0 
>   flutter: Alignment(-1.0, 0.1)

You can see that the y value 0.090858... was rounded up to 0.1 in the Alignment object which made me lost my precision that I need for my app.

How to make sure that Alignment Object does not round up my number? All I want is that y value stays to be 0.09085830765468121 instead of 0.1.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision is not lost.

When you print an object in dart the object's `toString` method is called to get a string representation of the object which is then printed to the console.

And the `toString` method of Alignment class is this

```dart
...
    return 'Alignment(${x.toStringAsFixed(1)}, '
                     '${y.toStringAsFixed(1)})';
```

and toStringAsFixed docs say

> the result is the closest string representation with exactly [fractionDigits] digits after the decimal point. If [fractionDigits] equals 0 then the decimal point is omitted

If you execute this

```dart
  const y = 0.09085830765468121;
  const x = -1.0;

  print(Alignment(x, y).y);
```

The output is as expected `0.09085830765468121`.

Comment: Exceptional, Great answer!